# Should we perform db operation using @PathVariable in Spring?

Tags: spring

GET should be used for viewing something, without changing it, while POST should be used for changing something. For example, a search page should use GET, while a form that changes your password should use POST.

So in Spring we have @PathVariable annotation and we can access it in our controller.

My questions is:
1)Should we use path variable in our controller to perform any DB operation like delete or update as it seems clearly in the URL.If yes then it can be a hole in our application that anyone can make that request again.

I know that we can use @RequestParam with POST method in spring as well as with GET method but I just want to know that if it is okay to use PathVariable to change our database.

Comment: Whether you use path variables or not doesn't matter much. Any request can be sent multiple times if you want to send it multiple times. What matters is to use the appropriate verb. Basically GET = get or search something, POST = create something, PUT = update something, DELETE = delete something.

Comment: if we use GET then the url with variable is saved on client browser and user can make that request again (same as with path variable) by just past that request but in case of POST method user actually does not able to do so

Comment: A user can write a script, install an HTTP client, use curl or whatever to send any request he/she wants to send. Whether you use path variables or not. Whether you use GET, POST, PUT or DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of @RequestParam, @RequestBody, or @PathVariable. You should check for correct user ROLES to do the database operation as long as these three methods can be automated using tools. Pure case of logic!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, obviously user role matters more but what if authenticate user just copy and paste that url again in browser

Comment: Usually normal users don't stage such activities. If someone is doing so, either he needs it or leave it as his 'KARMA'. In the end, it is his stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is no matter if you use `@PathVariable` or `@RequestParam`.

I think the important part you have to think about is, that you can use **hidden input fields**. And they can be catched with the `@RequestParam` annotation.

So I would say it depends on what you want to show in your url and what you want to "hide".